# "...cannot be resolved to type" error message; no method suggestions in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, types

Ok guys I've got a question that for the life of me I cannot get figured out. I'm using Eclipse, and I've got the Android ADT pluging all installed, the program configured with the Android SDK path, and all the extra SDK parts downloaded (Google API's, SDK Platforms, System Images).  Here is my problem: whenever I go to access a method from a certain object, Eclipse gives no method "suggestions" like it usually does.  I'm probably not explaining this the best, so I've attached a screenshot that kind of illustrates the issue.

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
TextView display;   


    //putting add.whatever here doesn't work


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
    counter = 0; 
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    //putting add.whatever here doesn't show suggestions either.
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get it working, deleting & reinstalling eclipse, deleting everything Android from with Eclipse and going through all the SDK setup again, changing my workspace, creating an entirely new project, deleting the Eclipse preference file, endless Googling, resetting & altering settings, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: First, don't post pictures of your IDE.  Copy and paste the code, and comment the line its happening on.  Second, have you imported the class (Button I think?  I can't read it)?

Comment: The image is indecipherable. Please replace it with one that is cropped to show the relevant part at larger scale. Or (better yet), get rid of the image, post the relevant code and describe exactly what error message you are getting and what line of code it is pointing to.

Comment: problem is not in eclipse. inside class suggestion for user defined member variable or member function can't be performed.u can do in method or any block.

Comment: Ok image is gone.  Problem has to be with Eclipse, whether it's in the onCreate() method body or not it doesn't show any method suggestions.  And yes, I have imported, hence the "Button add;" declaration is not underlined in red.

Comment: Misinterpreted part of your post at first, Sam, but ended up figuring it out. Thanks